# How to addToSet a value in array of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema

```
 UserSchema = {
    username: String,
    /*Other stuffs*/
    knows_about : [{topic: {type:String, ref:'Topic'},
                    bio: String}]
 }

 TopicSchema = {
    title : {type: String, required: true, index: true},
    followers : Number,
    thumbnail : String,
    created_date : {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    created_by:{type:String, ref:'User'}
 }
```

I am trying to add the topic object with id and bio to the array. 
$push works, but what I wanted was to push the topic only if the topic id doesn't exist, if it exist then instead of pushing it updates the bio in case the user decided to update the existing bio.

I can use User.find to find the user and then loop through the array to see if the array contains the object with the matching topic id, Is there a different way?

Comment: What you are describing are the storage semantics of a plain object using the id as the key. Do you need the array?

Comment: @Matt I'm using the array to push all the topics the user knows about so that when i call the user profile later i can populate the array since the topic schema has the topic title and thumbnail, i would like to display those results when i query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) would make life a little easier. This allows you to query and update the array directly but would still require two queries for your total operation as an upsert doesn't work with the positional operator.

Update existing title.

```
col.findOneAndUpdate(
  { user: "waldo", knows_about: { $elemMatch: { title: "Whatever" }}},
  { $set: { "knows_about.$.bio": "some bio" }}
)
```

Or if no records were found/updated then update with a [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

```
col.findOneAndUpdate(
  { user: "waldo" },
  { $push: { knows_about: { title: "Whatever", bio: "new bio" }}}
)
```

I don't know of a really simple way to manage that Mongoose schema.

Comment: The problem with this schema is there's no where to store the topic's ID. I'm using the ID to populate the data from another schema called Topic to get the Topic's title and thumbnail. I have updated the question

Comment: The mongoose realisation came after. Updated with a solution that means you don't have to deal with the arrays directly but still needs two queries.